# How to use For Loop in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a working SSIS that reads from a flat file from //MyPath1/test.txt, it populates a table and goes on doing other stuff. I would like to change the beginning of the import routine by making the SSIS reads from a single table with multiple rows that have different paths for example:

```
my table will show the following records with one column:
    row1: //MyPath1/test.txt
    row2: //MyPath2/test.txt
    row3: //MyPath3/test.txt
```

I am thinking of looping through my table records and for each record I want to point my package at the first path and execute the entire package, then comeback again and execute the package with path2 and so on...not sure how can this be accomplished?

Comment: There are many ways to do it, I would do a select on your table, get the path into an object variable from the select, then do a for/each loop through the data set.  Then in the for each loop container, read from the file you pulled from your path (you can use expressions to set the data source to the variable name).

Comment: Thanks Brad, would you by any chance have a link or example on how to do that? I think this is exactly what I am after. Google search returns a lot of examples of creating parameters